# Open two different links images in one window on one click

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to open two different links images in one window on one click.

For example, there are two different images link but i want to open both the images in same window on one click. i have tried open two different links or images on one click but they opened it in other window i want to open the both the images in the same window or new window but they must open in one window, adjacent to one another

This is what i m doing to open links in two other windows on one click

```
<a href="http://www.example.org" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','newwin');">click me</a>
```

Comment: You can't do that since browsers don't support that. You can create a page with two images or create two broswer windows.

Comment: Can i somehow open the two images in adjacent frames within the same window ? I have a large number of pair of images so it's not possible to create a page for every pair. Is this possible by javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this

<script>
function openLink(firstlink,secondlink){
document.getElementById('linkopen').innerHTML='<iframe src="'+firstlink+'"></iframe><iframe src="'+secondlink+'"></iframe>';
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="openLink('http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com');">Open two Link</a>
<div id="linkopen"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, pass the URLs for both images that you want opened inside the anchor's href, and rel attributes, like so `<a href="imageURL1" rel="imageURL2" />` and then handle the opening of both images with jQuery, get the `rel`, and `href` values, load them by assigning both images to `src` Like so:

```
$(imgSelector1).attr("src",imageURL1);
$(imgSelector2).attr("src",imageURL2);
```

Don't forget to handle the click event and pass control so that they execute the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a page that accepts a list of (url encoded) urls as a query parameter, like so

```
?url1&url2&url3
```

and then that page can use javascript to load all the images from the query string urls

```
urls = location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
  $('body').append($("<img>").attr("src", urls[i]));
```